# Python return several value to add in the middle of a list

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a function that returns several elements like this:

```
def foo():
  return 'b', 'c', 'd'

print ['a', foo(), 'e'] # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: You have a list and a tuple here (`foo()` returns a tuple). Python does have an `array` module but that's something different again.

Comment: You can do this in Python 3 with tuple unpacking: `['a', *foo(), 'e']`. Yet another reason to upgrade!

Answer (score 9):

You can insert a sequence into a list with a slice assignment:

```
bar = ['a', 'e']
bar[1:1] = foo()
print bar
```

Note that the slice is essentially empty; `bar[1:1]` is an empty list between `'a'` and `'e'` here.

To do this on one line in Python 2 requires concatenation:

```
['a'] + list(foo()) + ['e']
```

If you were to upgrade to Python 3.5, you can use `*` unpacking instead:

```
print(['a', *foo(), 'e'])
```

See [*Additional Unpacking Generalisations*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) in  *What's New in Python 3.5*.

Demo (using Python 3):

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 'b', 'c', 'd'
...
>>> bar = ['a', 'e']
>>> bar[1:1] = foo()
>>> bar
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> ['a'] + list(foo()) + ['e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> ['a', *foo(), 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it in a single line?

Comment: @Vinz243: You can use concatenation: `['a'] + list(foo()) + ['e']`

Comment: @Vinz243 If your only goal is to have a single line code you could do something insane like: `(lambda x: x.__setitem__(slice(1,1), (1,2,3)) or x)(['a', 'e'])`. Fortunately in this case list concatenation isn't really that bad, but the point is: sometimes making things fit in a single line is simply not worth it.

Comment: @NizamMohamed yes, this is new in Python 3.5. I'll clarify.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use this simple piece of code:

```
import itertools

def foo():
  return 'b', 'c', 'd'

l = ['a', foo(), 'e']
x=list(itertools.chain(*l))
print x
```

> Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Comment: This only works because strings like `'a'` and `'e'` are themselves iterable. It won't work for integers or other non-iterables nor will it produce correct output for strings with more than one character, or empty strings.